# Bypass mobile view feature only for a particular page

Tags: mobile, device-channel

I have a list that uses an edit form customized with a JsLink. Basically this form is heavily customized and I made it responsive so it looks pretty good in a mobile browser. I activated the **Mobile browser view feature** on my site and I'm trying to make my SharePoint site use the out of the box mobile layout for everything except my edit form.

I tried by using **"mobile=0"** in my query string but the problem is that SharePoint will use the view mode mentioned in the query string even after the user navigates away from the edit form. So after I navigate from the edit form, all the other pages will use the desktop view, which is pretty bad.

I'm thinking that maybe I can use a **device channel** to achieve this but so far I had no luck with that either. I cannot tell the device channel to target one page in particular.

Basically I'm trying to keep the edit form use the normal view layout and the rest of the site use the mobile view layout.

Thank you for your time!